# How can I create an Android and IOS widget

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, nativescript

I'm a JS developer and I want to develop a widget for my hybrid application. My application is developed using IONIC framework. I know that Cordova doesn't support developing widgets. The question is, is there any JS framework or any other framework in which I can develop Widget. But I don't want to develop for IOS and Android separately. I want a hybrid type.